# Show only decimal digits in Java if it is a real decimal digit

Tags: java, string, format

Sometimes a double can have an integer value and sometimes it can be a "real decimal digit".

I am searching for a way to print only the decimal digit if it has not a integer value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double test = 1; // should print "1"
    double test2 = 1.5; // should print "1,5"

    System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", test));  // OUTPUT: "1,0"
    System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", test2)); // OUTPUT: "1,5"
}
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Regards

Comment: 1.5 and 1,5 are not same according to arithmetic. This type of format would required string manipulation(convert float value to string).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    public static boolean isInteger(double num){

       if (num % 1 == 0){
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }

    }
```

It checks whether or not the number contains a decimal value.
If the method returns true, then you can cast it to a long or int.

Answer (score 0):

```
//obtain an array of strings based on the comma as delimeter
String[] array = java.util.Arrays.toString(String.valueOf(test).split("\\,"));

//if the second string (the decimal part) is not 0, then print both strings with a comma in between, othwersise only the integer part
if(array[1].equals("0")==false)
    System.out.println(array[0]+","+array[1]);
else
    System.out.println(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For decimal numbers you can specify how many number behind , you want

```
public static void printNumber(double num){

       if (num % 1 == 0){
           System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", num));
       } else {
           System.out.println(String.format("%.1f", num));
       }

    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double test = 1; // should print "1"
    double test2 = 1.5; // should print "1,5"

    printNumber(test);  // print 1
    printNumber(test2); // print 1,5

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through regex

```
 double test2 =1.5;

    if(!Double.toString(test2).matches("\\d+\\.0+")){ // matchs test2 whether it contains 0s after .(decimal) or not
                System.out.println(test2); //1.5
System.out.println(Double.toString(test2).replaceAll("\\.", ","));// 1,5
            }
```